# sendkeys() function is slow within the Selenium Grid2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am using firefox version 26 on 32 bit windows OS.
Sendkeys() function work with webdriver well but when run with the selenium grid its too slow (takes 2-4 seconds to each keystroke)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is expected as there is an extra layer of the hub/node between your test and browser. Another factor which adds to execution time is the test machine configuration(Processor, RAM,....) and network latency. One thing which you should make sure on your test machines is to have atleast a dual core processor.

Comment: Currently we are using I5 Generation machine with windows 7

Comment: The magnitude of delay of several seconds should not be expected. Yes, Grid by default is slower but we should be talking in terms of milliseconds not seconds.  I would suggest you have issues within your network which impacting your performance